# Architecture of approval process

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, patterns-and-practices

I want to design an approval process for my work flow but I wonder if there is an architecrural pattern or desing pattern for this solution.

For example an engineer will create a **work**. And `program manager` will approve it. Then `general manager` will approve it. The steps may be more. Then all users will see the work. Or another department users will see the approved **work**.

Comment: [Choosing the right Design Pattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/227880/31260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github allows for setting up protected branches, so only certain admins can approve pushing/merging into that branch.

You can set up a branch specifically for these checks, then from there merge into the master (or to-be-deployed) branch.

A simpler way to do this would just be use Trello or Zenhub or any ticketing program (Trac, Redmine) to implement the approvals.

Just keep in mind having a process and enforcing it are different challenges.

P.S. I've found having multiple individuals approving work can ofter slow development time down tremendously, so try not to put the approval on work that needs to flow through the organization quickly.